# using remote filesystem in docker, best practices

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, sshfs

I'm trying to dockerize my home multimedia setup build on OrangePI/RaspberryPi mini-servers. This question is rather about good practices, since i already have everything working without docker.

Currently my architecture looks like this:

- sshfs/encfs remote filesystem mounted on startup - this is main storage for media files
- minidlna service that consumes that fs in readonly mode
- samba (read/write), ftp (readonly) services
- transmission daemon service on top of the same storage

And some other services, but you get the idea, main storage is mounted from remote location.

To get to the point: should I (A) create docker service for each of abovementioned services? Should I (B) mount fs in host and then provide it to dockerized services?
Should I (C) create single super-container for all of them?

I'm lacking experience in this area and looking for advice.

Answer (score 0):

We can definitely rule out (C). From a best practice point of view it is almost always advisable to run one process per container. There are different schools of thought but main idea behind this is to be able maintain different dependencies for different services. Might not be applicable in your case but samba and minidlna might be requiring different versions of the same dependency.

Between (A) and (B) I would possible go for (B) so that this removes the overhead of mounting each file system over and over in each service container.